Zoom Out animation in Swift UI
I am trying to achieve an zoom out Animation is Swift UI. But the animation I am getting is not the intended one.
I want an animation that feels the ImageCarousel getting zoomed out to URLImageView and the titleButtonView moving up.
Below is the sample Code
struct ImageAndTitleView: View {
@State private var isVStack: Bool = true

// MARK: Private Variables
private struct Defaults {
 static let bigImageSize: CGFloat = 216
 static let smallImageSize: CGFloat = 80
 static let spacing: CGFloat = 8.0
 static let imageSpacing: CGFloat = 12.0
 static let image: String = "image"
 static let title: String = "tittle"
 static let subtitle: String = "subtitle"
 static let button: String = "button"
 static let lineLimit: Int = 3
 static let cornerRadius: CGFloat = 8.0
 static let borderWidth: CGFloat = 1.0
 static let padding: CGFloat = 16.0
}

// MARK: - Body
let images = [URL(string: "https://picsum.photos/400/200")!, URL(string: "https://picsum.photos/400/200")!, URL(string: "https://picsum.photos/400/200")!] // Replace with actual image names
let title = "Its can be a 3 lines long title"
let subtitle = "the subtitle goes here"

@Namespace private var animation

var body: some View {
 VStack {
   if isVStack {
     VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: Defaults.spacing) {
       ImageCarousel(images: images, size: Defaults.bigImageSize)
         .frame(width: isVStack ? UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 32 : Defaults.smallImageSize, height: Defaults.bigImageSize)
         .matchedGeometryEffect(id: Defaults.image, in: animation)
       TitleAndButtonView
     }
   } else {
     HStack {
       VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: Defaults.spacing) {
         TitleAndButtonView
       }
       .padding(8)
       
       URLImageView(url: URL(string: "https://picsum.photos/100")!)
         .frame(width: Defaults.smallImageSize, height:Defaults.smallImageSize)
         .padding(Defaults.spacing)
         .background(Color.white)
         .cornerRadius(Defaults.cornerRadius)
         .matchedGeometryEffect(id: Defaults.image, in: animation)
         .overlay(
           RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: Defaults.cornerRadius)
             .stroke(Color.blue, lineWidth: Defaults.borderWidth)
         )
     }
   }
 }
 .padding()
 .onAppear {
   startLayoutChangeTimer()
 }
}

private func startLayoutChangeTimer() {
 DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) {
   withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.45).delay(0.1)) {
     withAnimation(.spring()) {
       isVStack = false
     }
   }
 }
}

var TitleAndButtonView: some View {
 VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: Defaults.spacing) {
   Text(title)
     .font(.headline)
     .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
     .lineLimit(Defaults.lineLimit)
     .matchedGeometryEffect(id: Defaults.title, in: animation)
   Text(subtitle)
     .font(.subheadline)
     .matchedGeometryEffect(id: Defaults.subtitle, in: animation)
   Button(action: {
     // Button action
   }) {
     Text("Button")
   }
   .matchedGeometryEffect(id: Defaults.button, in: animation)
 }
}

struct ImageCarousel: View {
 let images: [URL]
 let size: CGFloat
 
 var body: some View {
   ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
     HStack(spacing: Defaults.imageSpacing) {
       ForEach(0..<images.count, id: \.self) { index in
         URLImageView(url: images[index])
           .frame(width: size, height: size)
           .padding(Defaults.spacing)
           .background(Color.white)
           .cornerRadius(Defaults.cornerRadius)
           .overlay(
             RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: Defaults.cornerRadius)
               .stroke(Color.blue, lineWidth: Defaults.borderWidth)
           )
           .padding(.trailing, index < images.count - 1 ? 0 : Defaults.imageSpacing) // Adjust padding to show part of the next image
       }
     }
     //      .padding(.leading, 10) // Padding at the beginning
   }
   .frame(height: size + Defaults.padding)
 }
}

struct URLImageView: View {
 let url: URL
 @State private var image: UIImage? = nil
 
 var body: some View {
   ZStack {
     if let uiImage = image {
       Image(uiImage: uiImage)
         .resizable()
         .scaledToFit()
         .clipped()
     } else {
       Color.gray
         .onAppear {
           loadImage()
         }
     }
   }
 }
 
 private func loadImage() {
   URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
     if let data = data, let uiImage = UIImage(data: data) {
       DispatchQueue.main.async {
         self.image = uiImage
       }
     }
   }.resume()
 }
}
}

any help is highly appreciated.
